# How to project in MongoDB after sort?

Tags: mongodb

In `find` operation fields can be excluded, but what if I want to do a `find` then a `sort` and just after then the `projection`. Do you know any trick, operation for it?

[doc](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find): `fields {Object}, the fields to return in the query. Object of fields to include or exclude (not both), {‘a’:1}`

Answer (score 3):

You can run a usual find query with conditions, projections, and sort. I think you want to sort on a field that you don't want to project. But don't worry about that, you can sort on that field even after not projecting it.

If you explicitly select projection of sorting field as "0", then you won't be able to perform that find query.

```
  //This query will work
  db.collection.find(
  {_id:'someId'},   
  {'someField':1})
  .sort('someOtherField':1)

  //This query won't work
  db.collection.find(
  {_id:'someId'},   
  {'someField':1,'someOtherField':0})
  .sort('someOtherField':1)
```

However, if you still don't get required results, look into the [MongoDB Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)!

Here is the sample query for aggregation according to your requirement

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$match: {_id:'someId'}},
{$sort: {someField:1}},
{$project: {_id:1,someOtherField:1}},
])
```