# Select array within a single record with mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I have a document which hold data like this :

```
{
    "data":"string"
    "arrayofdata" :[
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is select only the array of data from a single document

I'm trying to get this kind of format :

```
{ arrayofdata: [{},
                {},
                {}]}
```

What I tried gives me this kind of result which is not good :

```
[ { arrayofdata: {} },
  { arrayofdata: {} },
  { arrayofdata: {} } ]
```

### Any idea how to acheive that ?

Here is what I'm working with for now :

```
async findSubElement(collection: string, subElementName: string, filter: {
    id?: number,
    offset?: number,
    limit?: number,
    order?: number,
    sort?: string,
    fields?: string[],
  }): Promise<any[]> {

    try {
      const aggregatePipeline: any = [];

      aggregatePipeline.push(
        {
          $unwind: '$' + subElementName,
        },
      );

      if (filter.sort) {
        filter.sort = subElementName + '.' + filter.sort;
      }

      // then we can apply filter on these documents
      aggregatePipeline.push(
        {
          $match: {
            _id: new ObjectID(filter.id),
          },
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            [filter.sort ? filter.sort : subElementName + '.created_at']: filter.order || 1,
          },
        },
        // Then, use the offset
        {
          $skip: filter.offset || 0,
        },
        // And the limit
        {
          $limit: filter.limit || 20,
        },
      );

      const fields: any = {};
      // If the user specified fields, build the 'fields' object in a Mongo way
      if (filter.fields && filter.fields.length > 0) {
        filter.fields.forEach(field => {
          fields[field] = '$' + subElementName + '.' + field;
        });
      } else {
        // If the user didn't specify any field, use a default value
        fields[subElementName] = 1;
      }
      fields['_id'] = false;

      // finally we "project" only the fields of our wanted subDocuments.
      aggregatePipeline.push({
        $project: fields,
      });

      const agg = await this.aggregate(
        collection,
        aggregatePipeline,
      );
      const result = await agg.toArray();

      return result.filter(a => a);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `$unwind` stage and simply use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) instead like so:

```
aggregatePipeline.push(
  {
    {
      $project:
      {
        "_id": 0 /* get rid of _id explicitly */,
        "arrayofdata": "$arrayofdata" /* only include arrayofdata field */
      }
    }
  }
);
```

With respect to your comment: Yes, you can do that using a standard `findOne()`, too. Actually, all of what you do up there in your code can and hence should be done without using the aggregation framework. Mind you, `sort()`, `skip()` and `limit()` are only available if your query can return more then one document, so for `findOne()` none of them would work. They all do work, however, using `findMany()`:

Your $match turns into a bog-standard filter (the first parameter to findOne) like this:

```
collection.findOne({_id: new ObjectID(filter.id)})
```

Your `$project` will be the projection parameter to the findOne method:

```
// exclude "_id", include "arrayofdata"
collection.findOne({...}, {"_id": 0, "arrayofdata": 1})
```

The `$sort` stage turns into a `.sort()` command:

```
// I'm not sure about the square brackets here but if your code works then this should work, too.
collection.findOne(...).sort([filter.sort ? filter.sort : subElementName + '.created_at']: filter.order || 1)
```

Be careful about the sort part, though, and make sure you understand this: [How to project in MongoDB after sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708954/how-to-project-in-mongodb-after-sort)

The same for `$skip`:

```
collection.findOne(...).sort(...).skip(filter.offset || 0)
```

And also for `$limit`:

```
collection.findOne(...).sort(...).skip(...).limit(filter.limit || 20)
```

Putting it all together, here's a valid query which may or may not make sense in your data context but it's syntactically correct:

```
collection.find({_id: ObjectId("597fa64617a1cdcf9ace4712")}, {"_id": 0, "arrayofdata": 1}).sort({"arraydata":1}).skip(10).limit(20)
```

Comment: There is an idea here but I need it to be generic. So I have to use subElementName which is a string of the sub element I want to keep. If I do  : `subElementName: '$' + subElementName` with your method I get this result : `[ { subElementName: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]`

Comment: Can't I achieve that with findOne() method ?  I'm so bad at Mongo

Comment: I don't quite understand your "being generic" comment here. Can you please clarify (I recommend updating your question with more concrete examples)?

Comment: Generic as in the header of the method `findSubElement`. I should not use hard code like in your example`"arrayofdata"` but the parameter `subElementName`. It could be any field passed in parametter of the method.

Comment: Well, that you can easily achieve in the way you described in your first comment or am I missing something...?!